# Setting the video quality for an extracted YouTube video using 'libvideo' .NET library

Tags: c#, .net, youtube

I need help with a code to download video with better video quality 720p/1080p including audio using 'libvideo'.NET library.

I have used 'GetVideo' in the code but the downloaded video is defaulted with '360p' resolution.
So I am trying out this in the code (max resolution is set as '1080p').

```
var videoInfos = youTube.GetAllVideos(link);
var maxResolution = videoInfos.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Resolution == 1080);
```

But how do I use 'GetAllVideos' to save the video with the resolution that I have set it in the code.

[image]

https://github.com/omansak/libvideo

Comment: Use GetVideo(maxResolution) to get the selected resolution but be aware. Using GetAllVideos will fetch all available videos but it looks like the ones with the highest resolution dont include audio. I, myself, try to find a solution to this for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this, way.
I download the high res video. And then download the video with Audio, extract the Audio with the MediaToolkit Nuget and put it together with FFmpeg
For the mp3 Tags i used TagLibSharp

```
private async Task<string> Download(string Url, string Title, string Interpreter, bool AudioForVideo = false)
{
    string audioPath = "";
    try
    {
        YouTubeVideo video;
        if (AudioForVideo || !cbDownloadVideo.Checked)
        {
            video = youtube.GetVideo(Url);
        }
        else
        {
            IEnumerable<YouTubeVideo> videos = youtube.GetAllVideos(Url);
            video = videos.OrderByDescending(o => o.Resolution).ThenByDescending(o => o.Fps).First();

        }

        string fileName = video.FullName;

        if (Title != "")
        {
            fileName = $"{Title}.mp4";
        }
        if (AudioForVideo)
        {
            fileName = fileName.Replace(".mp4", "_temp.mp4");
        }
        string videoPath = Path.Combine(Settings.Default.DownloadDirectory, fileName);

        File.WriteAllBytes(videoPath, video.GetBytes());

        if (!cbDownloadVideo.Checked || AudioForVideo)
        {
            audioPath = videoPath.Replace(".mp4", ".mp3");
            MediaFile inputFile = new(videoPath);
            MediaFile outputFile = new(audioPath);
            using (Engine engine = new())
            {
                engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);
                engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile);
            }
            File.Delete(videoPath);
            if (!AudioForVideo)
            {
                TagLib.File mFile = TagLib.File.Create(audioPath);
                mFile.Tag.Title = fileName.Replace(".mp4", "");
                mFile.Tag.Artists = new string[] { Interpreter };
                mFile.Save();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (video.AudioFormat == AudioFormat.Unknown)
            {
                string audioInputPath = await Download(Url, Title, Interpreter, true);
                string tempVideoPath = videoPath.Replace(".mp4", "_output.mp4");
                FFMpeg.ReplaceAudio(videoPath, audioInputPath, videoPath.Replace(".mp4", "_output.mp4"));
                File.Delete(videoPath);
                File.Move(tempVideoPath, videoPath);
                File.Delete(audioInputPath);
            }
        }
        exception = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exception = ex.Message;
    }
    return audioPath;
}
```